# Specify BitBucket commit id in JSON file

Tags: json, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm working on a Bitbucket pipeline deploying into AWS. The pipeline builds a Docker image, pushes it to ECR, and ultimately deploys it into ECS Fargate. In the pipeline, I am using this Bitbucket [pipe](https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&p=atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image) to build and push the Docker image. This pipe has an attribute `TAGS` where I have specified `'${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}'`, so that each time an image gets built and pushed to ECR, the image will have the commit ID as the tag for the image. I have learned about this `'${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}'` from [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/)

I am facing a blocker when it comes to the deploy step with Fargate. I am using this [pipe](https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&p=atlassian/aws-ecs-deploy) to deploy to Fargate. This pipe has an attribute for `TASK_DEFINITION` which needs to be specified since with each deployment, the image that is being deployed has a different tag. The `task_definition` file is a JSON file that is in the repository. In that file there is a JSON object for the image. Below is the file with the object being discussed:

```
{
  "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/image:latest"
}
```

I had tried changing this JSON object into

```
{
  "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/image:${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}"
}
```

but that seems to destroy the entire JSON object. I tried seeing if there is a solution to specifying variables within JSON values, but it seems only function calls can be done in this context. If anyone can push me in the right direction to solve this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: don't!

Publish all images with your commit ID, that's fine for tracking.

For the deployment pipe, retag the already public image with the deployment environment slug and simply use that for your task definition:

```yaml
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:

    - &deploy-step
        oidc: true
        image: amazon/aws-cli
        services:
          - docker
        caches:
          - docker
        script:
          - docker login your.registry.com
          # Retag images :BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER as :BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT
          - docker pull your.registry.com/image:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
          - docker tag  your.registry.com/image:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER your.registry.com/image:$BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT
          - docker push your.registry.com/image:$BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT
          - # update services with the new image

pipelines:
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          name: Deploy to testing
          deployment: test
          trigger: automatic

      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          name: Deploy to production
          deployment: production
          trigger: manual
```

I use `$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER` instead of `$BITBUCKET_COMMIT` because I could potentially run different pipelines on the same commit and also creates a sequence that is easier to understand by humans.

But the big idea here is to retag the image with the deployment slug.